# How do I use matplotlib to create a bar chart of a very large dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The data I am working with is an array 27,000 elements long which is a histogram of a few million data points but what I have is the histogram and I need to plot it in my program, preferably with vertical bars.

I've tried using the 'bar' function in matplotlib but this takes a minute or two to plot whereas using just regular plot (with just points on the chart) is almost immediate but obviously does not achieve the effect I want (i.e. bars). I'm not sure why the bar function is so much slower so I was wondering if there was a more effective way to plot a histogram with vertical bars using matplotlib?

I've looked at the hist function with matplotlib but it's purpose to my understanding is to take data, make a histogram, and then plot it but I already have a histogram so I don't believe it works for my case. I greatly appreciate any help!

Here's a reference to the hist function documentation, maybe I missed something.
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Thanks in advance! Let me know if you would like an example of the code I am working with but it is just your most generic `my_axes.plot(my_data)` or `my_axes.bar(my_data)` so I'm not sure how helpful it would be.

I've taken a look at this as well now: https://gist.github.com/pierdom/d639a1d3b8934ee31db8b2ab9997ae92.

This also works but has the same time issue as using bar so I suppose this is just an issue with rendering a lot of vertical bars? (though I still wonder why rendering 27000 points happens so quickly)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a better way, but wanted to comment that you're probably on the right track. I suspect MPL would take as long as you're seeing for the number of data points you have.

Comment: So I think this guy accomplished what I was thinking, basically you use your histogram values as the weights in the hist function but time is still an issue so I suppose that just comes with rendering that many vertical bars. 
https://gist.github.com/pierdom/d639a1d3b8934ee31db8b2ab9997ae92

@zerecees Thanks for the reply btw!

Comment: Did you already look into plt.stem ?

Comment: @AlecPetersen no problem! I had a similar problem over the weekend, and found this helpful. Hopefully, it helps you! [MPL Fast Style](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#using-the-fast-style)

Comment: @zerecees That was super helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known and discussed limitation of the bar graph as it is currently implemented. See this [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15411) and this [discussion](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/bar-graph-performance/13561/5). Though there are questions about it's usefulness, in my particular case I have a toolbar across the top that allows the user to zoom in and move around the data set (which is very practical method for my use case).

However, a great alternative does exist in the form of [stairs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stairs_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stairs-demo-py). Simply use fill and you have an effective bar graph, that is much more performant.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

bins = range(27001)  # Note that bins needs to be one greater then heights
heights = [random.randint(0, i) for i in range(27000)]

ax = plt.gca()
ax.stairs(heights, bins, fill=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib's `bar` should be pretty fast to execute so I'm guessing you're passing all the data points to it (although you mention you have "histogram data", so if you can provide more details on the format, that'd help).

`bar` takes the x positions for the bars and the heights, so if you want the `bar` function to produce a histogram you need to bin and count.

This will produce something similar to matplotlib's `hist`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = [0, 1, 2, 3]
heights = [1, 2, 3, 4]

ax = plt.gca()
ax.bar(bins, heights, align='center', width=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a 27,000 element long array which is the histogram of a larger dataset, so I no longer need to calculate a histogram I just need to plot the bars of the array I have. When I increase the arrays in your example to match that length it takes a few seconds whereas the regular plot method takes far less than a second. I think it is weird too, but I don't see a way around it. Does make me wonder what they are doing that is so different between the two methods.